# HTTP authentication: how to debug .htpasswd?

Tags: apache, mod-security

My server outputs the authentication form, but the credentials i give are always wrong. Probably apache can't read my .htpasswd. Do you know how could I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using the [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/) (`mod_security`) application firewall module?  (That's what the tag indicates, but...?)

If so -- or in any case -- first rule out the simpler problem:  Review your host's `httpd-error.log` (or similarly named) log file, and make sure that your situation is not due to an Apache auth misconfiguration or related problem.  E.g. you might see `authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch` (or for whatever path in your case).  There is a good amount of advice on SO if you search on `htaccess` and `htpassword`, or look at posts tagged with [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess), [htpasswd](/questions/tagged/htpasswd), or [authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication).

If you're using Apache httpd version **2.4.4**, note that there is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54735) in the `htpasswd` utility released with it.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797767/2489297) elsewhere for workarounds relative to it.

Good luck!