# htaccess 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-authentication

Alright so I'm having a problem using htaccess to password protect a page. Every time I navigate to the page they are redirected to a "Internal server error" page. I have very minimal knowledge of PHP and am having a hard time getting this fixed. I took a look in the error logs and found this error here   "[error] [client 209.91.179.158] client denied by server configuration:"

I have no idea how to access the httpd.conf file on the FTP server nor do I know if it's possible. I have only been using PHP for about 2 weeks.

My .htaccess File

```
<Directory>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Allow from 209.91.179.158
   Allow from ::1
</Directory>
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile mydir/.htpasswd
<Files "staff.html">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/15478077/1741542

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 500 error because `<Directory>` directive isn't allowed in `.htaccess`. If you can explain what you're trying to do I can help you further.

Comment: I was trying to password protect a couple pages. I found an alternative but would still like to know how to do so.

Comment: Sure I can help but need little more info. e.g. what are the URLs that you want to password protect?